# Batch file to monitor a processes RAM, CPU%, Network data, threads

Tags: batch-file, process, monitor

I need to generate a report (periodic, say every 1 minute) that whilst run, generates the following in a txt file (or other):

For a given process...
Timestamp : RAM : CPU% : Network data sent/received for last second : Total network data sent/received : threads

I believe in Process Explorer the network data sent/received for last second is called the Delta.

Could you recommend how I might capture this using either a plain batch file, or relying on another tool if required? Such as power shell or PsList? Or at least, point me in the direction of the applicable tool that'll report all these things for a given process? And ideally, be able to report these from a process running on a remote machine if possible! Many thanks, knowledge gurus!

Answer (score 2):

```
logman create counter cpu_mem_trh -c "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" "\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes" "\Process(*)\Thread Count" -f csv -cf C:\PerfLogs\perflog.csv
logman update cpu_mem_trh -si 60 -v mmddhhmm
logman start cpu_mem_trh
```

to stop the performance counter use:

```
logman start cpu_mem_trh
```

[Here are all available performance counters.](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-performance-counters.html)

[And here's the logman help.](http://ss64.com/nt/logman.html)

For remote machine try with `\\machine name` prefix on each counter path or with `-s` option.Time intervals are set with `-si` option on the update verb. Path to the report is set with `-cf` option.

Comment: Thanks for these starting points. However, I've put the following together, with some errors when run:

Logman delete counter cpu_mem_trh

logman create counter cpu_mem_trh -c "\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time" "\Memory\Pool Paged Bytes" "\Process(*)\Thread Count" -f csv -cf C:\testlogging\perflog.csv
logman update cpu_mem_trh -si 60 -v mmddhhmm
logman start cpu_mem_trh

PING 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 4000 >NUL

logman stop cpu_mem_trh

pause

Comment: Errors are that 'Argument 'counter' is not allowed with the other arguments specified. The parameter is incorrect.   Then Error: The data collector already exists.  All other commands seem to complete successfully.  However, the folder and output CSV file are not created. (Using windows 7 by the way) Many thanks for any further help you can offer with getting this starter batch file working.

Comment: you cannot create a counter with the same name twice.To delete it use `delete` verb after stopping it.

Comment: Hi - unfortunately it doesn't fix the problem. For example, even with deleting the counter or renaming it on the next batch file run, I still end up with a .blg file and no created folder containing the CSV file. I changed the values in the .bat so that data was captured every second for 4 minutes before the counter stopped. The result is a 128KB .blg file, and no output. Also when loading the .blg file, no data is displayed in windows performance monitor. Again - many thanks for your clarification :)

Comment: to log in .csv format you need `-f csv` switch. To convert .blg to csv use `relog` command (check the second link)